# iterate through classes in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

** Im running this on a popup page. therefore cant simply use "entry" class as it clashes with the original page.

I want to iterate through classes to pick out the text, from the "entry" class

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
```

[image]

When I pick the xpath of this elemnt from chrome , its coming like this

But this isnt working with `driver.find_element_by_xpath(/html/body/span/div[1]/div/div[3])`

But below one is working, but its giving me date, heading etc. But I just want the text

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui_overlay").text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this xpath it will locate correctly :

```
".//span[@class = 'ui_overlay ui_modal ']//div[@class='entry']"
```

Example use:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Jars\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
url="https://www.tripadvisor.com/Airline_Review-d8729164-Reviews-Cheap-Flights-TAP-Portugal#REVIEWS"
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

langselction = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.sprite-date_picker-triangle")))
langselction.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='languageList']//li[normalize-space(.)='Portuguese first']").click()
gt= driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".googleTranslation>.link")
for i in gt:
    i.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    x = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@class = 'ui_overlay ui_modal ']//div[@class='entry']")
    print x.text
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui_close_x").click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

It will print the corresponding text

Comment: How can i get the text. Im getting this output after using this <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d66bb4ecc83d6cba4e0733ae1c762701", element="0.600939209536614-24")>

Comment: @thebadguy rocks !. But can you tell me how are you able to get that xpath? In my chrome when I right click & copy  the xpath, its just /html/body/span/div[1]/div/div[3]

Comment: Basically it's creating custom xpath..not copying the xpath from chrome. Please accept it as answer as well.

Comment: @thebadguy  the code is failing erratically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40013400/selenium-python-webscrape-fails-after-first-iteration