# selenium python webscrape fails after first iteration

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Im iterating through tripadvisor to save comments(non-translated, original) and translated comments (from portuguese to english).
So the scraper first selects portuguese comments to be displayed , then as usual it converts them into english one by one and saves the translated comments in com_, whereas the expanded non-translated comments in expanded_comments.

The code works fine with first page but from second page onward it fails to save translated comments. Strangely it just translates only first comment from each of the pages and doesnt even save them.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
com_=[]
expanded_comments=[]
date_=[]
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\shalini\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def expand_reviews(driver):
    # TRYING TO EXPAND REVIEWS (& CLOSE A POPUP)    
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("moreLink").click()
    except:
        print "err"
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui_close_x").click()
    except:
        print "err2"
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("moreLink").click()
    except:
        print "err3"




def save_comments(driver):
    expand_reviews(driver)
    # SELECTING ALL EXPANDED COMMENTS
    #xpanded_com_elements=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("entry")
    time.sleep(3)
    #or i in expanded_com_elements:
    #   expanded_comments.append(i.text)
    spi=driver.page_source
    sp=BeautifulSoup(spi)
    for t in sp.findAll("div",{"class":"entry"}):
        if not t.findAll("p",{"class":"partial_entry"}):
            #print t
            expanded_comments.append(t.getText())
    # Saving review date
    for d in sp.findAll("span",{"class":"recommend-titleInline"}) :
        date=d.text
        date_.append(date_)


    # SELECTING ALL GOOGLE-TRANSLATOR links
    gt= driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".googleTranslation>.link")

    # NOW PRINTING TRANSLATED COMMENTS
    for i in gt:
        try:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",i)

            #com=driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui_overlay").text
            com= driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class = 'ui_overlay ui_modal ']//div[@class='entry']")
            com_.append(com.text)
            time.sleep(5)
            driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui_close_x").click().perform()
            time.sleep(5)
        except Exception as e:
            pass

# ITERATING THROIGH ALL 200 tripadvisor webpages and saving comments & translated comments             
for i in range(200):
    page=i*10
    url="https://www.tripadvisor.com/Airline_Review-d8729164-Reviews-Cheap-Flights-or"+str(page)+"-TAP-Portugal#REVIEWS"
    driver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    if i==0:
        # SELECTING PORTUGUESE COMMENTS ONLY # Run for one time then iterate over pages
        try:
            langselction = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.sprite-date_picker-triangle")))
            langselction.click()
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='languageList']//li[normalize-space(.)='Portuguese first']").click()
            time.sleep(5)
        except Exception as e:
            print e

    save_comments(driver)
```

Comment: Can you localize issue as there are too much code lines to analyze?

Comment: @Andersson the issue is that for the  first page (first loop of for) all the original as well as translated comments are getting saved in their respective lists ( com_ & expanded_comments ) But thereafter for all the pages only the first comment is getting translated and it then skips over to next page , without translating the rest of the comments. Just run this code and analyse the lists com_ & expanded_comments after 3rd/4th loop. That will give you an idea

Comment: @Andersson can you atleast tell me how can I skip over those comments which are in english(& hence dont have a "Google translate" widget under them)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 problems in your code

1. Inside method `save_comments()`, at the `driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui_close_x").click().perform()`, the method `click()` of a webelement is not an ActionChain so you cannot call `perform()`. Therefore, that line should be like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui_close_x").click()
```

2. Inside method `save_comments()`, at the `com= driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class = 'ui_overlay ui_modal ']//div[@class='entry']")`, you find the element when it doesn't appear yet. So you have to add wait before this line. Your code should be like this:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//span[@class = 'ui_overlay ui_modal ']//div[@class='entry']")))
com= driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class = 'ui_overlay ui_modal ']//div[@class='entry']")
```

3. There are 2 buttons which can open the review, one is displayed and one is hidden. So you have to skip the hidden button.

```
if not i.is_displayed():
    continue
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",i)
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work. I checked for 4 loops. But the only problem is that com_ is getting duplicate comments. I could see this while running your code itself, as all comments are getting translated twice. Thus len(com_) = 2 x len(expanded_comments). Kindly fix this issue. thanks

Comment: @shalini I'm not sure why do you said it opens each comment twice. I think  only the first one is opened twice because your CssSelector find all the google translate on this page and it found the "Most recent review" which is the same as first comment in the list. In order to get only google translate inside reviews, just add the ID REVIEWS to your CssSelector expression. Here is example: 
`gt= driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#REVIEWS .googleTranslation>.link")`

Comment: Im sorry but still the same problem. cat_ is getting duplicate comments, I can see the translation getting clicked twice for each of the comment. Hence as before, len(cat_) = 2 x len(expanded_comments), this is the only part where its stuck

Comment: @shalini I've updated the answer to solve 2 buttons issue. Please try.

Comment: if you try to observe the two lists after 4th iteration you'll observe theres a difference in both lists. There should be one to one correspondence between both lists , which isnt happening

Comment: can you atleast tell me how can I skip over those comments which are in english(& hence dont have a "Google translate" widget under them)